# How to loop over a list until it finds a match?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have this piece of code:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
name = 'smm'
allowed_domains = ['*']
start_urls = ['http://www.theguardian.com/media/social-media']
def parse(self, response):
    items = []
    #Define keywords present in metadata to scrap the webpage
    keywords = ['social media','social business','social networking','social marketing','online marketing','social selling',
        'social customer experience management','social cxm','social cem','social crm','google analytics','seo','sem',
        'digital marketing','social media manager','community manager']
    for link in response.xpath("//a"):
        item = SocialMediaItem()
        #Extract webpage keywords 
        metakeywords = link.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]').extract()

        #Compare keywords and extract if one of the defined keyboards is present in the metadata
        for metaKW in metakeywords:
            if metaKW in keywords:
                item['SourceTitle'] = link.xpath('/html/head/title').extract()
                item['TargetTitle'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
                item['link'] = link.xpath('@href').extract()
                outbound = str(link.xpath('@href').extract())
                if 'http' in outbound:
                    items.append(item)
    return items
```

The purpose of it is to compare the variable 'keywords' (a list) with the variable 'metakeywords', which are the webpage keywords extracted using `link.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]').extract()`. When comparing it, if a single match is found, it should extract the items and append them as shownb in the last if statement. However, it throws no result. I know it should throw something as I have inspected the webpage url (http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/). Chan anyone help?
Cheers!

Dani

Comment: It is not currently possible to answer your question for two primary reasons: (1) because of the structure of a "for" loop, the "keywords" variable takes on the value of each item in "metakeywords" one at a time; therefore your "if" statement is trivial as it will always evaluate to true. "keywords" is only a list if "metakeywords" is a list/collection of lists, and you do not show or specifically tell us what kind of object "metakeywords" is. (2) someone reading this code has no idea what the "item" object is, nor can they see how or when the "items" list was initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Magenta nova. I've updated the code.

Comment: thanks for the update, but read my first point again carefully. i think you need to read the python documentation on for loops if you haven't already.

Comment: I'll read it. In the meantime, could you please give me a hint ? I'm learning and I find it a little bit tough.

Comment: sure, i'll post an answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

see my comments between the lines of your code.

```
   def parse(self, response):
            items = []
            #Define keywords present in metadata to scrap the webpage
            keywords = ['social media','social business','social networking','social marketing','online marketing','social selling','social customer experience management','social cxm','social cem','social crm','google analytics','seo','sem','digital marketing','social media manager','community manager']
        for link in response.xpath("//a"):
            item = SocialMediaItem()
            #Extract webpage keywords 
            metakeywords = link.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]').extract()
```

what kind of data does .extract() return? can you give us an example? 
i'm not familiar with the library you're using.

```
            #compare keywords and extract if one of the defined keyboards is present in the metadata
            for keywords in metakeywords:
```

this is the first major problem. the variable defined before "in" in a for loop should 
share a name with any variable you've already defined. you should use a new name, like
"metaKW." the value of this variable is set dynamically as each item in "metakeywords" is examined by 
your for loop.

```
                if keywords in metakeywords:
```

because "keywords" takes on the value of each item in metakeywords one by one, this
statement will necessarily always evaluate to true, so it's trivial/unnecessary.
however, let's say you're actually referencing the keywords list you defined higher up in your code...
in that case, as you iterate through the metakeywords list (i assume it's a list or some other kind of
iterable), neither "keywords" nor "metakeywords" will change it's value. therefore you'll be asking
the same question over and over, without changing the terms of the question, and getting the same 
result. clean up some of these problems and let us know if you're still not getting the desired result.

```
                    item['SourceTitle'] = link.xpath('/html/head/title').extract()
                    item['TargetTitle'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
                    item['link'] = link.xpath('@href').extract()
                    outbound = str(link.xpath('@href').extract())
                    if 'http' in outbound:
                        items.append(item)
                        return items
```

edit, by way of being a bit more constructive:

the kind of loop you want to use is something like this...

```
for metaKW in metakeywords:
    if metaKW in keywords:
        # the rest of your code.
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing it! I'll work on the code. If I'm not wring, .extract() returns a list like: [u'<meta name="keywords" content="social media, social media marketing>']. I've tried your last edit suggestion but it still does not work. See my updated code.